# Is it possible to make only selected field selectable under select Tag in HTML

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML

```
<div class="col76 pull-left">
   <select class="m-wrap" id="T1Select" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
      <option class="placeholder" selected="" disabled="">Select T1</option>
      <option value="Chips And Chocolates">Chips And Chocolates</option>
      <option value="Ice creams">Ice creams</option>
      <option value="One">One</option>
      <option value="Popcorn">Popcorn</option>
      <option value="Snacks And Corn">Snacks And Corn</option>
      <option value="Soft Drinks">Soft Drinks</option>
      <option value="Tea And Coffee">Tea And Coffee</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I tried this way

```
  var valueone = One;
  var T1Val = $("#T1Select").val();

     if(valueone==T1Val)
         {
    $("#T1Select option").each(function(){
     if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() == valueone) {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    });
    }
```

How can i make only "One" selectable under the Select Tag dynamically??

http://jsfiddle.net/6kb7dhwq/10/

Comment: you cannot assign it like `var valueone = One;` change to `var valueone = "One";`

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it. You only need the value you are looking to make selectable and a loop to disable the rest of them:
http://jsfiddle.net/lsubirana/bajy5ntc/

```
var valueone = "one";

$("#T1Select option").each(function(){
    if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() !== valueone) {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For any select box to dynamically select a value you just need to pass the value in the selected box 
So you should be doing

```
 $("#T1Select").val("value of One or any element you want to select");
```

This works for me

```
 <div class="col76 pull-left">
<select class="m-wrap" id="T1Select" tabindex="1" style="width:100%;">
  <option class="placeholder">Select T1</option>
  <option value="Chips And Chocolates">Chips And Chocolates</option>
  <option value="Ice creams">Ice creams</option>
  <option value="One">One</option>
  <option value="Popcorn">Popcorn</option>
  <option value="Snacks And Corn">Snacks And Corn</option>
  <option value="Soft Drinks">Soft Drinks</option>
  <option value="Tea And Coffee">Tea And Coffee</option>
 </select>
</div>

$("#T1Select").val("One");
```

Hope this be of some help.

Happy learning :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var valueone = "one";

               $("#T1Select option").each(function(){
               if ($(this).val().toLowerCase() != valueone) {
                 $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }else{
                 $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
               });
```